# Practical difference between ECMA262 and ISO/IEC 16262

Tags: javascript, standards

Does anyone know which is the difference between the two standards (in fact they look equivalent)?

Thanks.

To be more precise, I've downloaded the two documents from their website and if you read the Index, they seem to be equivalent

Answer (score 5):

The ISO document (preview [here](http://webstore.iec.ch/preview/info_isoiec16262%7Bed3.0%7Den.pdf)) includes this text:

> The present third edition of 
>   ISO/IEC 16262 (published as ECMA-262 5th edition)

which implies that they are the same text.

The [ECMA-262 page](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) also says this:

> This edition 5.1 of the ECMAScript Standard is fully aligned with third edition of the international standard ISO/IEC 16262:2011.

The only substantive difference therefore seems to be that ISO will charge you CHF 238 for a copy, but ECMA will give it to you for free.

Comment: A digital copy of ISO/IEC 16262:2011 is available for free: http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c055755_ISO_IEC_16262_2011(E).zip

Answer (score 0):

262 is just the identifier given by Ecma General Assembly while 16262:XXXX is the identifier given by ISO/IEC (where XXXX is the year of the revision).

So, both documents stand for the same.

- ECMA-262 1st revision was published by ISO/IEC as 16262:1998.
- ECMA-262 2nd revision was published by ISO/IEC as 16262:2002.
- ECMA-262 3rd revision was published by ISO/IEC as 16262:2011.
- ECMA-262 5th revision and other standards like ECMA-402 and ISO/IEC 21778:2017 have been blished by ISO/ICE as ISO/IEC 22275:2018.

You can see the list of standards managed by Ecma, with the Ecma id and the ISO/IEC id:  https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Standard.htm